# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000 (Python - Flask)

Tags: python, flask, postman

I´m learning Flask and Postman, and currently, I'm trying to solve this problem. I've the next code lines on Python:

```
app=Flask(__name__) 
@app.route('/get_chain', methods=['GET'])
def get_chain():
    response={  'chain': blockchain.chain,
                'length': len(blockchain.chain)
            }   
    return jsonify(response), 200
app.run( host='0.0.0.0', port='5000' )
```

After run that, when I go to postman and run this:
GET: http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_chain
The console shows me this message:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000

Answer (score 0):

You probably want just `return jsonify(response)`, skipping the `200`, which is already included in a successful response

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify

Comment: Problems caused by typos should be called out in comments, not answers, as there is a specific close flag for typos (e.g. Not reproducible or was caused by a typo)